# cassandra shopping cart data modeling explain

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have seen this screenshot about a data modeling in cassandra for an shopping cart.

Can anyone explain me two questions?

Q1: why is cart_id a UUID and user_id a TEXT ?
Q2: why I need items_by_name when items_by_id table exists ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see the explanation in the above diagram, each table has a marker text on arrows which says for what queries these tables will be required. In Cassandra, you create schema based on your queries, which are required by application. So that answers your second question, if your application has a query like Q3 then you need to create that table. Otherwise no way you can find items by name. For second question it is more of architectural decision what kind of key you want.